# Keep Getting An Error Using VirtualPathProvider With MVC and Azure Storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, azure

I have defined a VirtualPathProvider for getting cshtml files from Azure Storage to use as Partial Views.

I get the following error at startup:

> The view at '~/Views/Home/Index.aspx' must derive from ViewPage,
>   ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl.

It seems my virtualPathProvider is stopping the razor view engine from being used.

Here is the VirtualPathProvider:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace VTSMVC.Helpers.Utilities
{
public class BlobStorageVirtualPathProvider:VirtualPathProvider
{
    protected readonly CloudStorageAccount accountInfo;
    protected readonly CloudBlobContainer container;
    public CloudBlobContainer BlobContainer
    { 
        get { return container; } 
    }

    public BlobStorageVirtualPathProvider()
    {

        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebCloud"])
        {
            case "Cloud":
                // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
                accountInfo =     CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
                break;

            case "Web":
            default:
                accountInfo = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                break;
        }

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = accountInfo.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container. 
        container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("stockreports");
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        // Check if the file exists on blob storage 
        //string cleanVirtualPath = virtualPath.Replace("~", "").Substring(1);
        string cleanVirtualPath = virtualPath;
        if (container.GetBlockBlobReference(cleanVirtualPath) != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return Previous.FileExists(virtualPath);
        }

    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        // Check if the file exists on blob storage 
        //string cleanVirtualPath = virtualPath.Replace("~", "").Substring(1);
        string cleanVirtualPath = virtualPath;
        if (container.GetBlockBlobReference(cleanVirtualPath) != null)
        {
            return new BlobStorageVirtualFile(virtualPath, this);
        }
        else
        {
            return Previous.GetFile(virtualPath);
        }
    }

    public override System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class BlobStorageVirtualFile : VirtualFile
{
    protected readonly BlobStorageVirtualPathProvider parent;

    public BlobStorageVirtualFile(string virtualPath, BlobStorageVirtualPathProvider parentProvider) : base(virtualPath)
    {
        parent = parentProvider;
    }

    public override System.IO.Stream Open()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            //string cleanVirtualPath = this.VirtualPath.Replace("~", "").Substring(1);
            string cleanVirtualPath = this.VirtualPath;

            // Retrieve reference to a blob
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = parent.BlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(cleanVirtualPath);

            //Retrive the memorystream
            blockBlob.DownloadToStream(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // TODO: log your error messages here
        }
        return ms;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting; 
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using VTSMVC.Helpers.Utilities;

namespace VTSMVC
{
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    // Register the virtual path provider with ASP.NET 
    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new BlobStorageVirtualPathProvider()); 
}
}
}
```

The connection to my azure storage seems to work as I have used it to save.

Anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @AntRadha - I gave up using VirtualPathProvider. I don't think I ever did solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of other users:

Pages need to derive from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage or similar base type. This can be done using @inherits in the .cshtml file.

The reason we don't need this normally is because the Views folder contains a web.config file that sets the default page base type to WebViewPage. Alternatively, you can copy the  section from this web.config file and put it in the main web.config file.